# How to add layers with new data to a ggplot with a POSIX axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm used to this if I want to add a point to a `ggplot`, it works just fine:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) + geom_point() +
    geom_point(x = 200, y = 20, size = 5, color = "blue")
```

But, I get problems if there's POSIX dates involved:

```
dat_1 <- data.frame(time = as.POSIXct(c("2010-01-01", "2010-02-01", "2010-03-01")),
                     y_1 = c(-1, 0, 1))
```

The basic plot works, of course

```
(my_plot <- ggplot(dat_1, aes(x = time, y = y_1)) +
    geom_point())
```

but adding another layer

```
my_plot + geom_point(x = as.POSIXct("2010-01-01"),
    y = 0, size = 5, color = "blue")
```

returns an error

```
Error in Ops.POSIXt((x - from[1]), diff(from)) : 
  '/' not defined for "POSIXt" objects
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting to numeric solves the issue:

```
my_plot + geom_point(x = as.numeric(as.POSIXct("2010-01-01")),
    y = 0, size = 5, color = "blue")
```

But it is not necessary if the mapping is in a `aes` wrapper

```
point_data <- data.frame(x = as.POSIXct("2010-01-01"), y = 0)
my_plot + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y), data = point_data,
                     size = 5, color = "blue"
```